# Адаптивный дизайн - расположение блоков

Tags: html, css

Есть шаблон адаптивного дизайна сайта https://jsfiddle.net/u0t72dgh/

В мобильном представлении (до `768px` - сверху вниз - одним единственным блоком) идёт шапка, потом содержимое, а уже потом правая колонка.

Я добавил дополнительную колонку и пытаюсь её заставить отображаться следующим образом: шапка -> содержимое -> левая колонка -> правая колонка. А ОТ `768px` и до 1024px разместить в правой части страницы содержимое левой колонки, а сразу за ним правой, а в левой части должен отображаться блок с содержимым. А уже от `1025px` переносить левую колонку с содержимым в левую часть, в итоге структура должна стать такой (слева направо): левая колонка -> содержимое -> правая колонка.

Вот эта картинка наглядно демонстрирует описанное выше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как этого достичь?

Comment: Реально в рамках чего? Если никто не запрещает пользоваться JS'ом - то почему бы и нет? Если JS использовать нельзя, а только CSS, то можно попытаться @media условиями сделать.

Comment: Исключительно средствами CSS. И шаблон адаптивный, в нём уже есть @media, но я как не пытался, не смог выстроить нужную последовательность :-(

Comment: Во-первых это стоит уточнить в вопросе (я про JS). Так, на всякий случай. Насчет самого вопроса. Я думаю, стоит пытаться играть с шириной контента и левого сайдбара. До 768 - контент 100%, левый сайдбар 100%, правый сайдбар 100%. Порядок элементов в HTML тот же. 768 - 1024 - отображать flex'ом, плюс ширина контента, скажем, 80%, ширина левого и правого сайдбаров по 100% от оставшегося (читайте про флексы (например)). Сложнее только с 1024+. Там уже нужно переносить левый сайдбар влево. Но, как я понимаю, в этом и заключается проблема?

Comment: Да, проблема в переносе. И это не просто проблема, это взрыв мозга....

Comment: Проблема скорее всего решается при помощи css grids. Но, так как их поддержка еще не организована, то и проблема, можно сказать, не решается :) По крайней мере, насколько мне известно (а мне известно многое, поверьте). Если я ошибаюсь, то я буду только рад, пускай меня поправят и ткнут носом в мою безграмотность, но решения я не вижу, честно. Хотя с точки зрения JS тут делов на 5 минут (если не меньше).

Comment: Просто не умеет еще пока CSS с DOM работать :) По крайней мере в том аспекте, о котором мы рассуждаем...

Comment: А как насчет Float + media запроси?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно скомбинировать флоаты и флексы и написать семантический код, используя специальные теги для этого (`header`, `main`, `section`, `aside`, `footer`).

В примере ниже, изначально ориентируемся на мобильные телефоны, поэтому по умолчанию ширину всех блоков оставляем нетронутой.

Затем, от `768px` до `1024px` мы применяем `float` к элементам внутри `main` (не забываем предотвратить выпадание дочерних блоков из `main`).

От `1025px` и далее мы применяем к тегу `main` флекс свойства и для дочерних элементов используем свойством `order`, для того, чтобы управлять их порядком расположения.

P.S.: высота указана лишь для примера.
P.P.S.: `footer` поставлен для того, чтобы показать, что дочерние элементы из `main` не выпадают.

Можете также посмотреть реализованный мною пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/DanilChugaev/pen/jZjGEP?editors=1100)

```css
header, footer, .content, .right-aside, .left-aside {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  main::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .content {
    width: calc(60% - 40px);
    height: 540px;
    float: left;
  }
  .left-aside,
  .right-aside {
    width: calc(40% - 40px);
    height: 250px;
    float: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 2 100%;
  }
  .content {
    order: 1;
    flex: 3;
  }
  .left-aside,
  .right-aside {
    height: 540px;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .left-aside {    
    order: 0;    
  }
  .right-aside {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>Шапка</header>
<main>
  <section class="content">Контент</section>
  <aside class="left-aside">Левый сайдбар</aside>
  <aside class="right-aside">Правый сайдбар</aside>
</main>
<footer>Подвал</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без flaot-ов.

http://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/ygZeEv?editors=1100

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.header,
.leftside,
.content,
.rightside {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 3em - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
}
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 12 0 100%;
  min-height: 3em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.leftside {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 2;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.content {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 8;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.rightside {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 2;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .leftside {
    order: 3;
    flex: 4;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    min-height: auto;
    height: calc(50vh - 3em - 16px);
  }
  .content {
    order: 2;
    flex: 8;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .rightside {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    order: 4;
    margin-top: 0;
    top: calc(50vh + 16px);
    width: calc((100% - 16px)/3);
    min-height: calc(50vh - 16px);
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    position: static;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .header,
  .leftside,
  .content,
  .rightside {
    flex: 12;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .leftside,
  .rightside {
    min-height: 25vh;
  }
  .rightside {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .content {
    min-height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="leftside"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="rightside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем случае, при заполнении блоков текстом блоки едут - http://joxi.net/xAe8BoRSpPjwM2.png

Comment: У меня ничего не едет http://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/ygZeEv?editors=1100

Comment: Вот средняя ширина по вашей ссылке http://joxi.net/V2VG378ixY6n7A.png

Comment: @kizoso ну дак надо голову включать, а не тупо копипастить со стека...

Comment: ваш код не подходит для блоков резиновой высоты, и как следствие для адаптивной верстки.

Comment: @kizoso ну не подходит, так не подходит. не хотите думать, не используйте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать на чистом css, без скриптов. Высота блоков может быть резиновая:

```css
        .header{
      background-color:#ff7369;
      width:90%;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .wrapper{
      position:relative;
      width:90%;
      margin:0 auto;
      background-color:#0dff78;
    }
    .wrapper:before,
    .wrapper:after{
      content:'';
      display:table;
    }
    .wrapper:after{
      clear:both;
    }
    .content{;
      background-color:#ff79b8;
      position:relative;
      float:left;
      left:20%;/*ширина левой колонки для десктопа 1 из 2*/
      width:60%;/*ширина контента для десктопа 1 из 2*/
      min-height:1px;
    }
    .aside-left{
      background-color: #fff595;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 20%;/*ширина левой колонки для десктопа 2 из 2*/
      left: -60%;/*ширина контента для десктопа 2 из 2*/
    }
    .aside-right{
      background-color:#97f5ff;
      width:20%;
      float:right;
    }
    /*media*/
    @media (max-width:1024px){
      .content{
        left:initial;
        width:70%;
      }
      .aside-left{
        float:right;
        left:initial;
        width:30%;
      }
      .aside-right{
        width:30%;
        position:relative;
        clear:right;
      }
    }
    @media (max-width:768px){
      .content,
      .aside-right,
      .aside-left{
        float:none;
        width:100%;
      }
    }
    /*media*/
```

```html
        <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">content</div>
      <div class="aside-left">aside-left</div>
      <div class="aside-right">aside-right</div>
    </div>
```